# html/javascript - Change label text

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have a label on my page and I want to change the text of that label when a button is pressed. I have used the following code but nothing happens to the label.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changePrice(){
    document.getElementById('price11').innerHTML = '2.99';
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<label for="price1" id="price11">5.00</label>
<input type='button' onclick='changePrice()'/>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, where's the script located on your page?

Comment: @tymeJV I first placed the script in the head and then after the html code. Neither way worked.

Comment: Hmm... Can you bring up your console and see if there are any errors?

Comment: @tymeJV Im using notepad so cant see any errors

Comment: In your browser, the editor is irrelevant.

Comment: Weird, I created a Js fiddle and it doesnt work eitherb but it looks fine to me, Uncaught ReferenceError: changePrice is not defined

Comment: @Stokedout Make sure you use "No wrap" mode in the fiddle, otherwise you can't access the function from an `onclick` handler.

Comment: I am not getting any errors in the console

Comment: Works in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/B5MB2/

Comment: @Barmar - nice one thanks for the tip ;-)

Comment: Dont know why it doesnt work for me

Comment: I have worked around it by having another label with new text. The button hides the old label and shows the new label. Is this a good way?

Comment: Matt Can you post your code somewhere? I suspect it is something else which is breaking your JavaScript. The fiddle no wrap would not apply to your code.

As for your work around, there is no right answer I suppose. I think the pure JS solution would be cleaner as it does not require the inclusion of an extra DOM element.

Comment: In your old code, did you get any errors? What browser(s) did you test in? What was the value of `document.getElementById('price11').childNodes[0].nodeValue` after executing the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked around it by having another label with new text. The button hides the old label and shows the new label